# Issue converting MySQL TIMESTAMPDIFF() in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, timestamp

Can anyone suggest why these two queries are returning different results?
[image: queries]

As far as I know, data in the two DBs is identical, of TIMESTAMP datatype, with details up to the second. In Oracle, I tried to truncate to the minute before doing the difference, I also tried to round the difference before sum()... nothing seems to get me the exact same result as MySQL. We are talking about 1000records summing up.

Comment: What are the 2 dates, what are their datatypes? What do you get if you calculate on mysql?